# compact url query string in GET method

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want compact url query in GET method beacuse in my search form have input array there may be many and because of the browser they support a certain amount length url

For example :

```
example.com/search?case_control%5B%5D=1&case_control%5B%5D=2&case_control%5B%5D=3&case_control%5B%5D=4&case_control%5B%5D=5&case_control%5B%5D=6&case_control%5B%5D=7&case_control%5B%5D=8&case_control%5B%5D=9&case_control%5B%5D=10&case_control%5B%5D=11&case_control%5B%5D=12&case_control%5B%5D=13&case_control%5B%5D=14&case_control%5B%5D=15&case_control%5B%5D=16&case_control%5B%5D=17&case_control%5B%5D=18&case_control%5B%5D=19&case_control%5B%5D=20&case_control%5B%5D=21&case_control%5B%5D=22&case_control%5B%5D=23&case_control%5B%5D=24&case_control%5B%5D=25&case_control%5B%5D=26&case_control%5B%5D=27&case_control%5B%5D=28&case_control%5B%5D=29&case_control%5B%5D=30&case_control%5B%5D=31&case_control%5B%5D=32&case_control%5B%5D=33&case_control%5B%5D=34&case_control%5B%5D=35&case_control%5B%5D=36&case_control%5B%5D=37&case_control%5B%5D=38&case_control%5B%5D=39&case_control%5B%5D=40&case_control%5B%5D=41&case_control%5B%5D=42&case_control%5B%5D=43
```

In this example a small number is selected, but it may be much larger than this selected options
Is there a way to optimize these array inputs in url on GET method ?

Comment: Because i need pagination POST method restricts this task

Comment: you could implode array inputs and pass it as single param like `case_control=1,2,3`

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti this is good suggestion

Comment: Create a hash table of the possible parameter combinations and then do a lookup when the request is received.

Comment: save to session ?